# Reading data from command prompt and storing data in a string

Tags: c#, cmd

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393] (c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express>D:\sample1.bat C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express>echo ECHO is on. C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express>echo "Select * from Table" "Select * from Table" C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express>exit

I am getting output as above but i need only "Select *from Table"

Comment: What specific output... you're not being very specific here

Comment: what's the output now printing in 'S' string variable. post the now coming output and ask the desired output

Comment: i get the output as above in which i need to read only echo string variable i.e "Select *from Table""Select from Table"

Comment: @divya - Please edit the question to copy and paste output or error messages into the question. It makes it difficult for others to help you when it is in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Regular Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) to match the part of the string you want. Here I am looking for any characters that match the following pattern: `echo "{captured}"` and capture any characters inside the quotes.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string input = "Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393] (c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IIS Express>D:\\sample1.bat C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IIS Express>echo ECHO is on. C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IIS Express>echo \"Select * from Table\" \"Select * from Table\" C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IIS Express>exit";

Regex findEcho = new Regex("echo (?<echostring>\".*\")", RegexOptions.Compiled);

var matches = findEcho.Matches(input);
foreach (Match match in matches) {
    if (match.Success) {
        if (match.Groups["echostring"].Success) {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["echostring"].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Output: `"Select * from Table" "Select * from Table"`

[.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/W9SOE4)